# Master Ref ID is not working as expected in Details Table

Tags: django

I am getting this error message:
`{"status":400,"message":{"reason_items":[{"master_ref_id":["This field is required."]}]}}`

master_ref_id isn't supposed to be passed in postman(Details Table gets connected to Masters Table by master_ref_id which is autogenerated). But When I manually give master_ref_id, I get an obvious error:

`TypeError at /chargeback-reason/ django.db.models.manager.BaseManager._get_queryset_methods.<locals>.create_method.<locals>.manager_method() got multiple values for keyword argument 'master_ref_id'`

This is the data I am passing in postman for 'POST' request.

```
{
    "name": "name3",
    "action_id": 1,
    "reason_items": [
        {
            "attachement_format_id": 1,
        }
    ]
}
```

##### serializer.py file

```
class ChargeBackReasonDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = ChargeBackReasonDetails
        fields = '__all__'

class ChargeBackReasonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)    
    reason_items = ChargeBackReasonDetailsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ChargeBackReason
        fields = '__all__'


    def create(self, validated_data):
        item_row = validated_data.pop('reason_items')
        reason = ChargeBackReason.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item in item_row:
            ChargeBackReasonDetails.objects.create(**item, master_ref_id = reason)
        return reason
```

##### views.py file

```
def create(self, request):
    with transaction.atomic():
        data = dict(request.data)
        data['created_by'] = request.user.id
        data['updated_by'] = request.user.id
        data['updated_date_time'] = datetime.now(pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE))            

        for item in data['reason_items']:
            item.update({'created_by':request.user.id,'updated_by':request.user.id,'updated_date_time':datetime.now(pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE))})
        serializer = ChargeBackReasonSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({STATUS: RECORD_CREATED}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response({STATUS: status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, MESSAGE: serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

##### models.py file

```
class ChargeBackReason(models.Model):
    action_id = models.ForeignKey(ChargeBackAction, verbose_name="action_id", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='name')
        
class ChargeBackReasonDetails(models.Model):
    master_ref_id = models.ForeignKey(ChargeBackReason, verbose_name="Master Ref Id",related_name="reason_items",on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    attachement_format_id =  models.ForeignKey(AllMaster,verbose_name="Attachement Format",on_delete=models.PROTECT))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
class ChargeBackReasonDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ChargeBackReasonDetails
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['master_ref_id','']
```